# How to use the camera on my tablet android 13mP as a webcam for my computer?

Tags: webcam

I tried DroidCam and USB WebCam On Tablet PIPO T9 but they offer poor quality. Can anybody suggest me way to increase the quality through above mentioned apps or any other way that I can try.